# Get rid of double appendix

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

Good morning

There are already some threads about this. None of those really helped. I have main file like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{Sections and Chapters}
\author{Testy McTesty}
\date{ }

\usepackage[titletoc,toc,title,page]{appendix}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{\appendixname} 
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{\appendixname} 

\begin{document}
       \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    \section{Introduction}
    This is the first section.
        % Appendix
    \include{appendix}
\end{document}
```

And and appendix looking like this:

```
% Appendix

%\appendix       by the way, I have no clue what this was for...
\appendixpage
\noappendicestocpagenum
\addappheadtotoc

% List of figures
\cleardoublepage
{
    \listoffigures
}
% List of tables
\cleardoublepage
{
    \listoftables
}

% Bibliography
\cleardoublepage
```

If I run it like this I always get two appendix entries in the ToC. What's the source of this problem? In addition I'm wondering what `\appendix` used to do. I commented it out because it doesn't really changed anything.

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Do you really need `\include`? Try replacing it with `\input`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the call of `\addappheadtotoc` from the `appendix.tex` file which is included with `\include{appendix}`.

By saying `\usepackage[titletoc,toc,title,page]{appendix}` the appendix title page is already included in the `ToC`, which is pretty obvious from the `toc` option ;-)

In my opinion this is a 'bug' of the `appendix` package -- it does not check whether the package option `toc` is already specified when `\appappheadtotoc` is called.

[image]